# Davenport Reference for Prime Number Theorem

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

On page 40 in Harold Davenport's book "The Higher Arithmetic" he gives a reference in section 10 for an elementary proof of the prime number theorem as "Math. reviews, 10 (1949), 595-6" but I can't find it on MathSciNet. What reference is he referring to? I have fortunately been able to find similar though.

Comment: This [Goldfeld's paper](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf) explains the history of these two papers (from this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96437)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely either this [paper](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf) by Selberg from 1949, or this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063042/) by Erdős from the same year.

Comment: That's what I found too, doesn't correspond exactly to the reference but I am guessing that is what he meant.